# Android webview permissions

Tags: android, webview, permissions

I have to write an android app that wraps an existing website using the WebView component. Inside this website, users can do some video calls, after according access to the navigator using (Navigator permissions). The problem is how can i request the same permissions to make the calls possible. Because even requesting permissions in real time doesn't work, and the webview still have no access to Camera/Audio.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can ask all permissions at once before loading web view or you can use any library like [PermissionHelper](https://gist.github.com/digitalprecision/735820df14f696fc2c6c8b251b2b05d6) to ask permissions before any event is going to happen.